# Merge two dataframes with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, multi-index

I have seen several posts about this but I could not get my head around how merge, join and concat would deal with this. How can I merge two dataframes to find matching indexes?

in:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
row_x1 = ['a1','b1','c1']
row_x2 = ['a2','b2','c2']
row_x3 = ['a3','b3','c3']
row_x4 = ['a4','b4','c4']
index_arrays = [np.array(['first', 'first', 'second', 'second']), np.array(['one','two','one','two'])]
df1 = pd.DataFrame([row_x1,row_x2,row_x3,row_x4], columns=list('ABC'), index=index_arrays)
print(df1)
```

out:

```
             A   B   C
first  one  a1  b1  c1
       two  a2  b2  c2
second one  a3  b3  c3
       two  a4  b4  c4
```

in:

```
row_y1 = ['d1','e1','f1']
row_y2 = ['d2','e2','f2']
df2 = pd.DataFrame([row_y1,row_y2], columns=list('DEF'), index=['first','second'])
print(df2)
```

out

```
         D   E   F
first   d1  e1  f1
second  d2  e2  f2
```

in other words, how can I merge them to achieve df3 (as follows)?

in

```
row_x1 = ['a1','b1','c1']
row_x2 = ['a2','b2','c2']
row_x3 = ['a3','b3','c3']
row_x4 = ['a4','b4','c4']
row_y1 = ['d1','e1','f1']
row_y2 = ['d2','e2','f2']

row_z1 = row_x1 + row_y1
row_z2 = row_x2 + row_y1
row_z3 = row_x3 + row_y2
row_z4 = row_x4 + row_y2

df3 = pd.DataFrame([row_z1,row_z2,row_z3,row_z4], columns=list('ABCDEF'), index=index_arrays)
print(df3)
```

out

```
             A   B   C   D   E   F
first  one  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1
       two  a2  b2  c2  d1  e1  f1
second one  a3  b3  c3  d2  e2  f2
       two  a4  b4  c4  d2  e2  f2
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.DataFrame.reindex` + `pd.DataFrame.join`
`reindex` has a convenient `level` parameter that allows you to expand on the index levels not present.

```
df1.join(df2.reindex(df1.index, level=0))

             A   B   C   D   E   F
first  one  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1
       two  a2  b2  c2  d1  e1  f1
second one  a3  b3  c3  d2  e2  f2
       two  a4  b4  c4  d2  e2  f2
```

---

**Option 2**
You can rename your axes and `join` will work

```
df1.rename_axis(['a', 'b']).join(df2.rename_axis('a'))

             A   B   C   D   E   F
a      b                          
first  one  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1
       two  a2  b2  c2  d1  e1  f1
second one  a3  b3  c3  d2  e2  f2
       two  a4  b4  c4  d2  e2  f2
```

You can follow that up with another `rename_axis` to get desired results

```
df1.rename_axis(['a', 'b']).join(df2.rename_axis('a')).rename_axis([None, None])

             A   B   C   D   E   F
first  one  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1
       two  a2  b2  c2  d1  e1  f1
second one  a3  b3  c3  d2  e2  f2
       two  a4  b4  c4  d2  e2  f2
```

---